# How do I find all indexes of smallet value of array, if the smallest value appears multiple times?

Tags: javascript

Like the question says, I want to find all Math.min values (more specifically their indexes). If my question isn't clear enough, maybe this example would help:

Let's say I have the array [1, 31, 15, 1, 7, 1]. I want to find the indexes of the smallet value in that array, which is 1 - so the program should return [0, 3, 5]. Here's the small program I wrote:

```js
let arr = [1, 31, 15, 1, 7, 1];
let newArr = [];
for (let a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    newArr[a] = arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr));
    arr.splice(a, 1);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Yet the output is [0, 2, 1], and I don't understand why. If someone could point me in the right direction or help me understand why it doesn't work I would be extraordinarily happy! Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have always positive integers smaller than 2^32-1?

Comment: Yes, the integers would be at max at the 1000s.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most optimal solution with O(n),

```js
let arr = [1, 31, 15, 1, 7, 1];
let newArr = [];
let minimum = Infinity;
for (let a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if(arr[a] === minimum) { 
       newArr.push(a);
    } else if(arr[a] < minimum) {
       newArr = [a];
       minimum = arr[a];
    } 
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach changes the array with `splice`. This changes the indices and makes the given array invalid index wise.

Instead, you could collect all values with their indices and get the smallest one with more than one index as result.

A single loop approach:

```js
let array = [100, 31, 15, 100, 7, 100],
    indices = {},
    smallest = Number.MAX_VALUE;

for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const value = array[index];
    if (value > smallest) continue;

    if (!indices[value]) indices[value] = [];
    if (indices[value].push(index) === 2 && value < smallest) smallest = value;
}

console.log(indices[smallest]);
```

Comment: too much unnecessery operations, on big data it will give too bad performance

Comment: better, but indices is still not needed, just result array is needed, if next value is less than smallest make length = 0 or reassign an empty array and that's it

Comment: no, you need to keep other values and then take the smallest with at least two indices.

Comment: Haha, i do not think pierreh ment that, otherwise of course you are right

Answer (score 0):

An optimum solution is

```
const arr = [1, 31, 15, 1, 7, 1];
const indexes = arr.reduce(([indxs, minValue], v, ind) => {
  if (v > minValue) return [indxs, minValue]
  if (v < minValue) indxs = []
  indxs.push(ind)
  return [indxs, v]
}, [[], Infinity])[0] 

console.log(indexes) // [0, 3, 5]
```

Comment: hm, try with `1000` instead of  `1` and have in mind: "*...if the smallest value appears multiple times*".